# How to make long argument in function reflected in R

Tags: r, function

Thanks for all your helps.

I want to make macro with `function` with R. In `function`, there is long argument. This argument will not `print` or `return` specific value. But I want to make the results of arguments be reflected.

For example, I made some arguments with `dplyr`

The `i` will be dataframe. I created the dataset `test`

```
set.seed(1001)
a<-rnorm(10)
b<-rnorm(10)
test<-data.frame(cbind(a,b))
test
```

Then I want to make column `c`. The `c` will be `a` minus `b`

```
fun<-function(i){
i<-i%>%mutate(c=a-b)}
fun(i=test)
```

But, when i checked the `test`, the `c` variable was not generated.

How to make the results of arguments in function reflected?

Comment: add `return(i)` at the end of the function.

Comment: After execute the function, it returns test data set with c column, but when i command the results is still not reflected in test. Maybe test<-fun(i=test) should be done. Right?

Comment: yes, you need to assign it back. `test<-fun(test) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `return` in the function and assign the value back to `test`. Or since R by default returns the last line of the function, you can do

```
library(dplyr)

fun <- function(i) i %>% mutate(c = a - b)
test <- fun(test)
test

#        a      b      c
#1   2.189  0.303  1.886
#2  -0.178  1.634 -1.812
#3  -0.185 -0.622  0.437
#4  -2.507  0.467 -2.974
#5  -0.557  1.419 -1.977
#6  -0.144  0.110 -0.254
#7   1.092  1.870 -0.778
#8  -0.623 -1.030  0.407
#9  -0.907 -1.342  0.434
#10 -1.594  0.554 -2.148
```